# ForALL construct: Collection range can be initialized to a constant?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, forall

I want to use ForAll construct in procedure:

Existing For loop is:

```
      max_versions constant number := 100;
      FOR i IN 1 ..max_vers 
        LOOP
           l_sql := 'update test_table set p' || i ||'= NULL WHERE p' ||i||'=0 AND           condition1=' ||n_input1 ||' AND  condition3 = ' || n_condition3;
         EXECUTE immediate l_sql;

           l_sql := 'update test_table set h' || i ||'= NULL WHERE h ||i||'=0 AND                condition1=' ||n_input1 ||' AND  condition3 = ' || n_condition3;
         EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
        END LOOP;
```

Here max_vers is a constant 100 and p1...p100 and h1...h100 are columns in a table. In above query null is being set if columns' value is 0.

SO is it possible to use ForAll with a constant rather than collection?

I have tried to do below:
First, I tried to use direct constant with 'Count' method but since it is a method of collect

```
PROCEDURE Test
IS 

TYPE MaxVersTab IS TABLE OF number;
maxvers MaxVersTab := 100; 
                             -- Error1
BEGIN

    FORALL i IN 1 .. maxvers .count
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE -- Error2 and Error3
    'update test_table set p' || i ||'= NULL WHERE p' ||i||'=0 AND condition1=' ||n_input1 || ' AND condition3 =n_input3' USING maxvers(i);

    FORALL i IN 1 ..  maxversions.count
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'update test_table set p' || i ||'= NULL WHERE p' ||i||'=0 AND condition1=' ||n_input1 || ' AND condition3=n_input3'  USING maxvers(i);
```

I am getting different errors as below:

- Error 1) Expression is of wrong type
- Error 2) Statement ignored
- Error 3) the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete
  or malformed

My question is , can we assign a range to a collection(like 100) to be used in ForAll. Please let me know.

Regards

Comment: No. `Forall` only works with bulk binding with a collection, you can't simply use a constant. Alternatively, you should consider using ctas method for such bulk updates, which could be much efficient than `forall`. see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/updating-700-million-rows-to-same-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using For loop , I am using static query which would update h1..h100 and p1...p100 columns in one go.

```
l_sql := 'UPDATE sh_rpt_temp_peer_final t SET p1= NULLIF(p1, 0),--...NULLIF(p100,0),
h1= NULLIF(h1, 0)  --...NULLIF(h100,0),
where condition1=' ||n_input1 || ' AND condition3 =n_input3';
EXECUTE immediate l_sql;
```

This will reduce the number of query execution from 200 to 1

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use FORALL here.

> The FORALL statement runs one DML statement multiple times, with
>   different values in the VALUES and WHERE clauses.

You deal with different DML statements, not with the only one.
Your DML statements are different because you use different columns in it.

If you have one DML statement you can do something like this:

```
declare
  TYPE MaxVersTab IS TABLE OF number;
  maxvers MaxVersTab; 
  n_input1 varchar2(32767) := 'some_condition_string';
BEGIN
  select level
  bulk collect into maxvers
  from dual
  connect by level <= 5;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. maxvers .count
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'update test_table set p1 = null WHERE p1=:bind_variable1 AND condition1=:bind_variable2' using maxvers(i), n_input1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim and William for letting me know about the usage of ForAll construct. I am accepting your answers. Though I have used static query for updating all columns in a query rather than loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm how you **can't** use `forall`:

You can't invoke the `forall` mechanism on its own as a generator:

```
begin
    forall i in 1..100
        insert into demo(id) values (i);
end;
```

fails with:

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 38:
PLS-00430: FORALL iteration variable I is not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 3, column 9:
PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL
```

You have to actually use the collection.

To set up a collection of 100 elements, you have to `extend` it (so it can't be a constant, unless we write a function to initialise it with). The following runs, but it inserts nulls because we didn't generate any values:

```
declare 
    type number_tt is table of number;
    numbers number_tt := number_tt();
begin
    numbers.extend(100);

    forall i in 1..100
        insert into demo(id) values (numbers(i));
end;
```

You can populate the collection from a `select` (or some other approach), but we are now moving away from the idea of a quick way to prime `forall` with 100 values so that we can use it to execute some task 100 times.

```
declare 
    type number_tt is table of number;
    numbers number_tt := number_tt();
begin
    select rownum bulk collect into numbers
    from dual connect by rownum <= 100;

    forall i in 1..100
        insert into demo(id) values (numbers(i));
end;
```